# In regards to nlp-node nlp.JS, how to extract date when intent is "What date is today?

Tags: node.js, nlp

Software Version

- nlp.js   4.27.0
- node 18.16.0
- npm  9.5.1
- OS Win 10

I wanna extract date when intent is "What date is today?"'

I got answer to be "Today is {{date}}" and it returned "Today is today" per the log below.
I wish to have answer like "Today is 2023-08-14"... but how?
Below is the log I got....

```
"intent": "inquiry.today",
"score": 0.9992725501954545,
"domain": "default",
"sourceEntities": [
{
"start": 12,
"end": 16,
"resolution": {
"values": [
{
"timex": "2023-08-14",
"type": "date",
"value": "2023-08-14"
}
]
},
"text": "today",
"typeName": "datetimeV2.date",
"entity": "date"
}
],
"entities": [
{
"start": 12,
"end": 16,
"len": 5,
"accuracy": 0.95,
"sourceText": "today",
"utteranceText": "today",
"entity": "date",
"rawEntity": "datetimeV2.date",
"resolution": {
"type": "date",
"timex": "2023-08-14",
"strValue": "2023-08-14",
"date": "2023-08-14T00:00:00.000Z"
}
}
],
"answers": [
{
"answer": "Today is today"
}
],
"answer": "Today is today",
```

Comment: Thank you for reading the question. I found the solution from ChatGPT already.